# Why is thisJOptionPane program not closing when I click the no or cancel options?

Tags: java, swing, loops, exception, joptionpane

In the first dialog box of this program, clicking "yes", "no" or "cancel" all do the same thing. How do I make the program close if the user clicks "no" or "cancel"? Could I use some exception handling? Or maybe another loop?

```
package dice;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DialogBox 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalStateException
{
    int again = 0, money, guess, bet = 0;
    String message, message2, message3, guessStr, betStr, resultStr;
    Account account = new Account(100);

    IllegalStateException problem = new IllegalStateException("You're out of cash!");

    do
    {
     money = account.getCashValue();
     message = "You have $" + money + ". Would you like to bet?";
     JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message);
     betStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to bet?($): ");
     bet = Integer.parseInt(betStr);

     guessStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess the sum of two die, then press OK to roll the die.");
     guess = Integer.parseInt(guessStr);

     Dice dice1 = new Dice(6);
     Dice dice2 = new Dice(6);

     dice1.setValue();
     dice2.setValue();

     int diceSum = (dice1.getValue() + dice2.getValue());
     boolean win = Account.winBet(guess, diceSum);

     if (win == true) 
        resultStr = "You win! \n";
     else
        resultStr = "You Lose! \n";

     message2 = resultStr + "first die: " + dice1.getValue() + "\nsecond die: " + dice2.getValue() + "\nsum of die: " + diceSum;
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message2);

     account.newBalance(win, bet);
     money = account.getCashValue();

     if (money <= 0)
         throw problem;


    }
    while (again == JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message));
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't assigning the result of your confirmation dialogs to anything.

```
message3 = "You now have $" + money + ". Would you like to bet again?";
// vvvv
again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message3);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: I updated my code incorporating the changes you suggested . It helped(thank you!) but didn't fix the problem. Now, if you click "no" or "cancel" on the 2nd, 3rd, etc. window, it closes. But the first window still doesn't close regardless of which option you click.